# C make file -Wno-unused-parameter flag

Tags: c, linux, compiler-warnings

I am trying to compile some C code in Linux Kernel.
I have a huge project that compiles without any warnings. The compilation line is very very long and complex.

In project, the compiler did not warn about variables that are part of the function signature that were not used (even though it contains flags such as -Wall). such as:

```
void foo (int a) {
}
```

I cannot see why it would not warn on it. 
So i checked the actual compilation lines on the original project by running:

```
make -n
```

It does not have the flag -Wno-unused-parameter that cancels this warning.

Does anyone know of a flag that cancels this warning? Maybe a different flag that contains the -Wno-unused-parameter flag ?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: The warning `-Wunused-parameter`, in gcc version 4.2.1, is not part of `-Wall`.

Comment: The `-Wall` flag has a poorly chosen name. It's name, of course, suggests that _all_ warnings are enabled -- but that's simply a lie. I'm not sure if `-Wextra` picks up everything else, or just more, but it's at least a start.

Comment: @mah: `-Wextra` does include `-Wunused-parameter`.

Comment: Yes, `-Wextra` does include `-Wunused-parameter` but remember that it would enable the latter only if used with `-Wunused` or `-Wall`.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Warning Options - Using the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), `-Wall` doesn't enable `-Wunused-parameter`, so this warning isn't mysteriously cancelled, but simply not enabled.